# Trigger on ContentDocument

Tags: trigger

I'm trying to write a trigger on ContentDocument to align file access rights to the different user. I can align file access rights to the user when I upload a new version of the file. But to align the rights after I have uploaded a new file, the afterInsert trigger is not fired. Is there no afterInsert trigger on ContentDocument and do you know another way to implement that?

Comment: I believe you should be writing the trigger on ContentVersion object, not the ContentDocument object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trigger on ContentVersion object didn't work, so I have written a trigger on FeedItem object and it works.

Answer (score 2):

There is 3 things I would mention to you about the **ContentDocument** Object and **ContentVersion** Object.

**1.** ContentDocument object only supports **delete(), describeSObjects(), query(), retrieve(),                undelete(), update()** calls.

- A user can change ownership of a Salesforce CRM Content document or
         Chatter file if any of the following are true: The user is the
         current owner, or has either the “Modify All Data” or "Manage
         Salesforce CRM Content” permission enabled. The user has the “Manage
         Library” permission enabled for the library containing the document.
- **Documentation can be found here:** http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_contentdocument.htm

**2.** ContentVersion Object supports **create(), describeLayout(), describeSObjects(), query(), retrieve(), search(), update(), upsert()** calls.

- **Documentation can be found here:**
  http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm

**3.** Both the objects have the **ownerId** field with the following properties: **Create,  Group, Sort, Update**.

**Try writing the after insert trigger on the ContentVersion object**.
 Hope this was helpful.

**Code:**

```
trigger ContentVersion_OnAfterInsert on ContentVersion (After Insert) {
     //Write the logic
}
```

Comment: Hi subodhbahl, this answer does explain that ContentVersion should be used, but simply quoting documentation isn't all the best: providing an example would be even better!

Comment: @LaceySnr I understand that. The trigger is already written on ContentDocument object, try replacing the object name to ContentVersion and it should work. I don't think I should be writing a whole trigger for that. I specifically mentioned the ownerId field in my answer for the user to understand what I mean.

Comment: I wasn't saying you have to, just that the answer was flagged by a user and down voted because it didn't provide an example. Generally the more effort in the more votes you get :)

Comment: Aight, time to edit the answer. Thanks Matt! Hope the leg is better now ;)